# Preventing user from uncheking a checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes in my winforms program. I managed to make it somehow that only one of them can be selected by user. That is if user clicks one of the unchecked buttons, ofcourse that button will be checked and also the check will be removed from last checked button!

Now I want to do it somehow that user can not uncheck the checkboxes, so the only way to checkk a box will be clicking on it. is this possible? is there any property for this?

Sorry for using too much check & box :P

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent the Radio Button control?

Comment: I knew it can be done with radio button and a panel but I have to stick with checkboxes (They look cool!)

Comment: @Sean87 - "They Look Cool" is a poor reason for using a control over one that already provides this functionality in an expected way.  I wouldn't confuse your users with un-natural UI conventions.

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. The function of a common control is not to "look cool", it is to *present a clearly understandable control surface to the user* -- a user who is familiar with radio buttons. Users will be confused by checkboxes that are logically radio buttons; I assume that checkboxes are *checkboxes* and can be unchecked at will.

Comment: We just had one of our business analysts ask us if we could change all our radio buttons to look like checkboxes because he prefers the look. We told him "No"

Comment: Well the actual reason is that I already have used lots of radio buttons in the program, so for making it look better or atleast not confusing, I decided to use checkboxes in some parts of it (just near the radio buttons).

Comment: @Eric My idea is that only one check box can be checked, and also atleast one of them should be checked, so I needed this to prevent user to uncheck the only checked box...

Comment: Group your related radio buttons in a group box to keep them clear.

Comment: @Sean87:  So what you're saying is that you're already using radio buttons as radio buttons, but now you want to make checkboxes function as radio buttons also?  So you want to break with platform conventions _and_ your _very own program's existing conventions_?  Organize your interface in a better way.  If it makes sense, consider replacing some radio buttons with pick-lists.  There are _dozens_ of things you can do to fix your problem that will be kinder to yourself _and_ your users.

Comment: Yeah, my problem is solved by the answer, but I think I have to stick to the rules so I am going to use radio button and group boxes.

Comment: I don't understand why I got -1 rating and 1 vote for closing. My question is quite legit and breaks no rules! except for the right use of checkboxes!!!

Comment: I believe this question implicitly encourages counterintuitive UI/UX design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [checkedchanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) event of the checkbox write the following code.

```
if (!checkBox1.Checked)
 {
     checkBox1.Checked = true;
 }
```

Comment: No, no, no!  Don't use a checkbox!  This lets the checkbox be unchecked, then re-checks the checkbox; it doesn't prevent the checkbox from being unchecked.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a radio button functionality but a different look, change the appearance of a radio button.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.80).asp

```
private void InitializeMyRadioButton()
{
   // Create and initialize a new RadioButton. 
   RadioButton radioButton1 = new RadioButton();

   // Make the radio button control appear as a toggle button.
   radioButton1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;

   // Turn off the update of the display on the click of the control.
   radioButton1.AutoCheck = false;

   // Add the radio button to the form.
  Controls.Add(radioButton1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just listen for change events and if the event tells you the checkbox has been unchecked, recheck it.

But I agree with others, this behavior is the one of RadioButtons, so use a radio button instead. You don't want to suit your personal feeling but to provide a unified user experience to the end user. That's part of the guidelines of Microsoft (and every other framework).